# Are there subsets of $\mathbb R$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$ or $\mathbb Q_p$?

Tags: general-topology

The title says it all. I know that the middle-third Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, and there is a pretty explicit homeomorphism in this case, but what about for other primes $p$?

Is there a subset of $\mathbb R$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q_p$?

Comment: You can construct different types of Cantor sets, just divide an interval into $2p-1$ subintervals and take out the middle ones. What you get is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set for any $p$ (although it's a bit easier to first construct a homeomorphism to a Cantor set depending on $p$). $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set minus a point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f:\Bbb{Q}_p\to \Bbb{R}, f(\sum_{n=-N}^\infty a_n p^n)=\sum_{n=-N}^\infty \frac{a_n}{p} (2p)^{-n}$$ where I mean $a_n\in 0\ldots p-1$